# What does the second parameter in the generic argument of a Typescript-based React component stand for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm looking at using React with Typescript. On the official Typescript's [website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html), one of their guides have this set of code for a component:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>;
    }
}
```

At this line:

```
export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}>
```

I know the first parameter in the generic argument is probably referring to the property interface which has all of my properties (`this.props`).

What does the second parameter of `{}` in the generic argument stand for? It looks like an object, but what does it do and what I can have in there? How can I even use it?

I've tried searching about this, but there aren't much info on React with Typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the state of the React Component.
e.g.

```
export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {name: string}> {
    render() {

        return <h1>Hello {this.state.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh! Does that mean I can actually put my states in an interface too, just like the props in the example?

Comment: More information about this [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react)